# matplotlib xkcd with utf-8 label

Tags: ubuntu, python-3.x, matplotlib

I'd like a plot with a label:

```
plt.plot(np.sin(np.linspace(1,10)), label='fête')
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

Works great.  Now let's try with xkcd mode:

```
plt.xkcd()
plt.plot(np.sin(np.linspace(1,10)), label='fête')
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

No error, but the label is 'f?te'.  It seems possible that this is a font problem, so I'll add that this is linux (ubuntu).

Comment: I don't see this issue on OS X, so probably indeed not a bug in `matplotlib`'s code base, but a font problem on ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks for that test point.
Sadly, this may well be true (that it is ubuntu-specific). That will make it very hard, sadly, to file a bug. The font manifestly has the UTF-8 glyphs (testing with libreoffice).
I've posted the question at http://askubuntu.com/questions/567701/matplotlib-xkcd-with-utf-8-label , I'll follow on here and there if I find a satifying answer.

Answer (score 0):

Humor Sans font does not have that nor other glyphs.

When you write on LibreOffice it uses a backup font for those fonts that don't have the specified glyph, and that is what you are seeing, the backup font. For instance, notice that all the letters' glyphs in Humor Sans are upper case, even those you type lower case, but when you type letter with tilde or accents they are shown lower case with the tilde; that is because it is the backup font.

The problem does not happen if you use other comic-like fonts, like «Comic Sans» or «Stay Puft», although they are not as pretty.

On Windows or OSX the default is probably «Comic Sans» for matplotlib with XKCD.